# activeX button to copy a row of data from sheet 1 to Sheet 2 based off cell value

Tags: vba

I am new to stackoverflow.com and VBA. I have been searching the web for a VBA that will allow me to copy data from sheet 1 that I input and then paste into sheet 2 based off the a cell value match. Once it is copied, it would then clear the data on Sheet 1 without delete the rows.

I work in a call center, and this would be to update equipment based on the desk it is located at.

So I am hoping that once I input all the data into the fields on sheet 1, I can click an activex button and it will search for the desk number on sheet 2 in column A and then update the row (B:Q) with the data from sheet 1.

I have seen some VBA that will copy the data but it only copies to the next empty row of cells.

Here is the code that I have found but is just not right.

```
Sub MoveRowBasedOnCellValue()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    I = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:Q5" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = ("A5") Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & J + 1)
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help would be great!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the code below? I assumed the desk number are on column A sheet1 starting at row 2. You will need to adjust the end rows for both sheet though.

```
Sub MoveRowBasedOnCellValue()
Dim s1 As Sheet1
Set s1 = Sheet1
Dim s2 As Sheet2
Set s2 = Sheet2
Dim s1StartRow As Integer
Dim s1EndRow As Integer
Dim s2StartRow As Integer
Dim s2EndRow As Integer
s1StartRow = 2
s1EndRow = 8
s2StartRow = 2
s2EndRow = 10


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = s1StartRow To s1EndRow

 For j = s2StartRow To s2EndRow

   If s1.Cells(i, 1) = s2.Cells(j, 1) Then
    s1.Range("B" & i & ":Q" & i).Copy
    s2.Cells(j, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   End If

  Next j

Next i
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I applied the above code and made the adjustment. Here is how I currently have it.

Comment: Sorry, New to the site, didn't know about the 5 minute update rule here. 

Thank you for your input. This comes back with a Run-time Error '424': Object required message. 

The desk number is in Column A row 5 only for Sheet1 (Update) and Column A Row 3:1009 for Sheet2 (Floor). I have also change s1.Range("B"....to s1.Range ("A"....along with Row start/end to 1/17 (A:Q).

Comment: Hi if your Column A row starts at 5 then your rowstart for sheet1 should start at 5 also. I won't be able to troubleshoot the Error without seeing your full code. If you copy and paste the code above without replacing anything it returns an error for you?

Comment: Yes, Thank you so very much. I miss read the code at first but now I have it working. Thanks again. Super helpful.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.